# How to make date time like this?

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-5.3

Hi I am saving data from rss feed url. From that me got date time like this.

Sun, 2 January 2011 03:04:02 GMT+5:30

How to change this date to this format 2nd January 2011, 03:04 PM using php?
any body knows the solution please help me.

Comment: As per the comment on my question - the exact same code works perfectly for me. What's the problem? Also, have you correctly set the local timezone as per my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can se the [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert the existing string and the 'r' specifier to the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function as follows (looks like you want it in  RFC 2822 format, if not tweak accordingly):

```
date('r', strtotime("Sun, 2 January 2011 03:04:02 GMT+5:30"));
```

Incidentally, make sure you're setting your local timezone correctly via [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), etc.

Comment: Does `strtotime` manage to resolve the time zone, though? (off testing)

Comment: @Pekka - They call him "Doubting Pekka". Perhaps. Sometimes. (And rightly so.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka well, we all know that a bit of magic was involved when `strtotime()` was programmed, so I'm keeping a special eye on it. :) Good point about `date_default_timezone_set`. The date gets converted to the server's local time zone.

Comment: @learner The exact same code works perfectly for me. What's the problem? Also, have you correctly set the local timezone as per my comment?

Answer (score 1):

The following functions are useful for taking a string and getting a timestamp back:

- [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)
- [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

After you have it as a timestamp, you can reformat it using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). I'm not 100% sure if strtotime() would accept that format, but it should accept it because the format it isn't ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

`echo date("js F Y, h A", strtotime($oldDate));`

Comment: I think you have the [date()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format specifiers confused with those used by [strftime()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).